# Terminology question: $\sigma$-algebra generated on the codomain

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, terminology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-empty sets and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Furthermore, let $\tau$ be a topology and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra, respectively, on $X$. It is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
f(\tau)\equiv&\;\{E\subseteq Y\,|\,f^{-1}(E)\in\tau\}
\end{align*}
is a topology on $Y$, while
\begin{align*}
f(\Sigma)\equiv&\;\{E\subseteq Y\,|\,f^{-1}(E)\in\Sigma\}
\end{align*}
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

While there is a well-established terminology for $f(\tau)$: it is known as the [*final topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology), it seems to be the case that there is no similarly widespread name for $f(\Sigma)$.

I tried searching

- “*final $\sigma$-algebra/$\sigma$-field*” by analogy to the concept of the final topology; and
- “*pushforward $\sigma$-algebra/$\sigma$-field*” by analogy to the concept of the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure),

but these do not seem to be standard expressions.

Can anyone suggest a terminology for $f(\Sigma)$ that is widely recognized?

Answer (score 1):

I think the *induced* $\sigma$-algebra by $f$ (and $\Sigma$) is a term that's used, but I couldn't find a source, and the "bible" (i.e. Fremlin's five (!) "Measure Theory" books), defines but doesn’t  name it, at least not where I found it.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in Volume 1, 111X(c). In your opinion, would it be weird to call it “pushforward $\sigma$-algebra,” “image $\sigma$-algebra,” or “final $\sigma$-algebra”?

Comment: @triple_sec I found it in Fremlin too, just the fact that is *is* a $\sigma$-algebra, but not a name for it. I still prefer induced, though “final” or “image” is possible too. With filters it’s called the push-foward IIRC.